# Combination of Vectors in R of different Lengths

Tags: r, combinations

I have two vectors of zip codes (sites and customers). I am trying to find the combination of pairs between the two vectors.

Hence, if sites is size 3 and customers is size 4...I would expect 12 combinations. I am currently using crossing() to do this in R.

However, when I put in my actual data sites of size 20 and customers size 6057, the function returns 35,760 combinations when I expected 121,140 (6057*20) combinations. Does that mean that there were that many duplicated combinations and they were removed?

my code is copied below. Thanks in advance.

```
data <- read_xlsx("Sites.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet3")
data2 <- read_xlsx("Customers.xlsx", sheet = "Sheet1")

sites <- as.vector(data['FRT - Ship From Zip'])
sites

Customers <- as.vector(data2['Ship_To_Zip'])
Customers

Comdata <- crossing(Customers,sites)
Customers <- as.vector(Comdata['Ship_To_Zip'])
sites <- as.vector(Comdata['FRT - Ship From Zip'])
```

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: Without a reproducible example, as @sindri_baldur suggests, I can only speculate that there are only 35760 *unique* combinations of customer and site zipcodes. You can see `help(crossing)` states "find all unique combinations of x, y and z."

Comment: Pretty easy to check how many unique combinations there are... have a look at `length(unique(Customers))`. My guess is your 20 sites are unique and the number of unique customers is `35760 / 20 = 1788`.

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
expand.grid(x, y)

# Data
x <- 1:20
y <- 1:6057
```

Comment: @Dustin Smith is this what you were after?